# Proper identification of admin for admin_data on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, authorization

We have everything installed correctly, but when an admin goes to /admin_data it throws "not authorized".

heres the relevant code in config/initializers/admin_data.rb

```
AdminData.config do |config|
 config.is_allowed_to_view = lambda {|controller| return true if current_user.admin = true }
 config.is_allowed_to_update = lambda {|controller| return true if current_user.admin = true }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be the condition you're using to check equality:

```
if current_user.admin = true #will always be true
```

vs

```
if current_user.admin == true #will check the equality of being true
```

You might consider just:

```
if current_user.admin
```

since nil or false will be NOT == true